# Getting Problem In Creating Tab on Catalog Product Edit page at Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalog

I want to create tab in product edit area in magento, here is the code I and using but the tab is not added.
Can someone check and tell me whats the problem ?

**Emizentech_Nutriprof**

**config.xml-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Emizentech_Nutriprof>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Emizentech_Nutriprof>
  </modules>

  <global>
      <blocks>
        <nutriprof>Emizentech_Nutriprof_Block</nutriprof>
      </blocks>
      <helpers>
        <nutriprof>
          <class>Emizentech_Nutriprof_Helper</class>
        </nutriprof>
    </helpers>
  </global>

  <adminhtml>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <nutriprof>
          <file>nutriprof.xml</file>
        </nutriprof>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>

    <admin>
      <routers>
        <adminhtml>
          <args>
            <modules>
              <nutriprof before="Mage_Adminhtml">Emizentech_Nutriprof_Adminhtml</nutriprof>
            </modules>
          </args>
        </adminhtml>
      </routers>
    </admin>

</config>
```

**Emizentech/Nutriprof/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Tab.php-**

```
<?php

class Emizentech_Nutriprof_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Tab extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    mage::log("hi",null,"bye.log");
    public function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('nutriprof/catalog/product/tab.phtml')
    }
    public function getTabLabel(){
        return $this->('My Customt Tabs');
    }
    public function getTabTitle(){
        return $this->__('Click here to view your custom tab content');
    }
    public function canShowTab(){
        return true;
    }    
}

?>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/nutriprof.xml-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="paroduct_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>nutriprof</name>
                <block>nutriprof/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/nutriprof/catalog/product/tab.phtml-**

```
<div>
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Emizentech_Nutriprof>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Emizentech_Nutriprof>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <nutriprof>
                <class>Emizentech_Nutriprof_Block</class>
            </nutriprof>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <nutriprof>
                <class>Emizentech_Nutriprof_Helper</class>
            </nutriprof>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <nutriprof>
                    <file>nutriprof.xml</file>
                </nutriprof>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <nutriprof before="Mage_Adminhtml">Emizentech_Nutriprof_Adminhtml</nutriprof>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Change your tab class [Emizentech/Nutriprof/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Tab.php]

```
class Emizentech_Nutriprof_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Tab extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    /**
     * Set the template for the block
     *
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('nutriprof/catalog/product/tab.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the label used for the tab relating to this block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('My Custom Tabs');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the title used by this tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Click here to view your custom tab content');
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether to display the tab
     * Add logic here to decide whether you want the tab to display
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Stops the tab being hidden
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }


}
```

Change your layout xml config [app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/nutriprof.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTabAfter">
                <name>nutriprof</name>
                <block>nutriprof/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab
                <after>downloadable_items</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

Clear cache

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not working.
I placed die('hello'); in file 'Tab.php' but it didn't show anything.

Comment: It's tested code and it's working fine. Did you clear cache? OR Share your module.

Comment: Thanks Sohel for your answer, I really appreciate it. I dont know why my code was not working. then I found this link ,followed it and it worked.  https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/